# Isolate a hosts networking with iptables

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall

I want to isolate a host on my home intranet using `iptables` on my linux router.  So say for instance, I have a host that has the IP of `10.0.1.50` and I want it to be able to talk to the rest of the Internet, but I don't want the router to allow it to talk to any other host in `10.0.1.0/24`. However, I want to be able to allow hosts in `10.0.1.0/24` to connect to `10.0.1.50` on port `80` only as long as the connection isn't created on the host. I am doing this in case `10.0.1.50` is compromised, so it can't talk to the rest of my network.

Comment: it's related to your interfaces.please edit and explain more.

Comment: I am not sure what other information you are looking for. I have two interfaces on the router, a wan and lan. iptables is already setup as a NAT as well.

Comment: I read again , you don't ban in layer 4, you should do it in layer 3, you shoud ban in switch.

Comment: Because before your iptables hosts able to watch together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're most probably doing it wrong. Your router can't prevent `10.0.1.50` from talking to the rest of the `10.0.1.0/24` subnet, because they're in the *same subnet*. A packet from `10.0.1.50` to another host in this subnet will not pass through the router, so you can't filter it.

What you need to do is to set up a separate subnet, let's say for example `192.168.0.0/24` and put `10.0.1.50` into that subnet, for example with the new IP `192.168.0.50`. Then connect this subnet to a separate interface of your router, and configure this interface to an IP like `192.168.0.1`. Then you can set up your routing rules as desired:

- Allow established and related connections
- Allow `10.0.1.0/24` to connect to the Internet
- Allow `192.168.0.0/24` to connect to the Internet
- Allow connections from `10.0.1.0/24` to `192.168.0.50:80`
- Deny everything else

Comment: So I did that originally, so I am glad that that was the right path to take.  Originally, I had it so that the host was in 10.0.2.0/24 and my regular subnet was 10.0.1.0/24.  I added 10.0.2.1 to eth1 on my router, which also was 10.0.1.1.  However, I had a routing issue between the two networks, which didn't make sense to me. Thoughts?

Comment: *"Your router can't prevent 10.0.1.50 from talking to the rest of the 10.0.1.0/24 subnet, because they're in the same subnet"* - if the computers on the network are directly connected to the router, it should be possible to drop undesired packets even on the usually bridged LAN, shouldn't it?

Comment: @peterph I think you would have to connect each computer to a separate interface on the router and then you would have to set up a `/31` or `/30` mini subnet for each computer, which of course doesn't seem very practical. As soon as multiple computers are directly connected via hub/switch/bridge the packets between these computers would no longer pass through the router.

Comment: @sparticvs please try to restore this configuration then *[or: wait for other answers in case I'm wrong]* and then edit your posting to reflect it. Explain the issues you're having and then we can take it from there.

Comment: @MartinvonWittich well, once the packets have to physically go through the router, it is possible to intercept them - question is whether this can be done on layer 2 (i.e. a bridge, which is usually what the internals of home routers are) - I believe the functionality is there, commandable with [ebtables](http://ebtables.sourceforge.net/index.html). Of course, if you have just a "stupid" bridge somewhere ahead of the router, you're out of luck.

Comment: @peterph wow, you've got me there... I had never heard of `ebtables` before now :). Yes, that could work in the right circumstances, but unless you really need the ability to selectively pass or filter Ethernet frames, it's probably the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: Switched to VLANs.

Answer (score 0):

To do it you should ban in layer 3 not layer 4, or if you do in layer 4, you should define a new subnet.